# serialize null navigation property

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have simple class:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Address Address {get; set;} // can be null
}
```

When I query `Person` I want `webapi` return me empty `Address` property. I tryed the following:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include,

            };
```

but, nothing chaged, it's just not exist in result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to configure the formatter, just add $expand query option:

```
GET ~/Person?$expand=Address
```

I tried, it works. and I'm using WebApi OData for OData v4.

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://jinfutan13:9123/$metadata#Albums/$entity",
  "ID":5,"Name":"Name 5",
  "Singer":null
}
```

Where Singer is also a navigation property.